# arrange a tabHost above a list through an Activity

Tags: java, android, list, tabs, android-tabhost

I want to set a tabHost and a list one below the other, so I added it to a vertical linear layout but it crashes when I try to addView the tab host

```
    public TabHost peopleTabHost;

private void CreateNewTab(String tagName, String displayedName, Class<?> intentClass)
{
    Intent intent = new Intent().setClass(this,  intentClass);
    TabHost.TabSpec spec = peopleTabHost.newTabSpec(tagName).setIndicator(displayedName);
    spec.setContent(intent);
    peopleTabHost.addTab(spec);     
}

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      LayoutParams rootParams = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
      LinearLayout rootLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
      rootLayout.setLayoutParams(rootParams);
      rootLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
      LinearLayout.LayoutParams listParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(0, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
      listParams.weight = 1;
      ListView lv_chosen = new ListView(this);
      lv_chosen.setLayoutParams(listParams);
      lv_chosen.setTextFilterEnabled(true);

      peopleTabHost = getTabHost();
      CreateNewTab("groups", "Groups", GroupsActivity.class);
      CreateNewTab("everyone", "Everyone", EveryoneActivity.class);
      CreateNewTab("contacts", "Contacts", ContactsActivity.class);

      peopleTabHost.setCurrentTabByTag("everyone");
      rootLayout.addView(peopleTabHost);
      rootLayout.addView(lv_chosen);
}
```

thanks

Answer (score 0):

In `OnCreate()` you have to create the TabHost first:

```
// instead of peopleTabHost = getTabHost();
peopleTabHost = new TabHost(this);  
setTabHost(peopleTabHost());
```

Furtherthemore you have to create an inner layout the TabWidget and the content (FrameLayout). Therefore continue with

```
LinearLayout tabhostLinearLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
tabhostLinearLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
peopleTabHost.addView(tabhostLinearLayout);

TabWidget tabWidget = new TabWidget(this);
tabhostLinearLayout.addView(tabWidget); 

// the FrameLayout for the content
FrameLayout frameLayout = new FrameLayout(this);
tabhostLinearLayout.addView(frameLayout); 

// and finally
peopleTabHost.setup();
```

and this seems also to be missing at the end of `OnCreate()`:

```
 setContentView(rootLayout);
```

Because this is a lot of work, I recommend to use XML layout for this.

Comment: thank you, but at first I made the peopleTabHost like you showed and it crashed when I tried to add a new tab to it, when I made it like my code shows it didn't crash anymore. and I did define it if that what you mean, above the create new tab method. also, the method setTabHost(TabHost) is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

This is how it's done in the API demos:

http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/Support4Demos/src/com/example/android/supportv4/app/FragmentTabs.html

Resources:
http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/Support4Demos/res/layout/fragment_tabs.html

I think going with an XML-layout will be better, just as suggested by CodeDownZero.

Comment: and a lot of it's imports can't be resolved, on my computer at least, shuold I download a special package

Comment: It's just an example of how to modularize the tabs of a TabHost as Fragments.
Just edit the example into something that you need, the key is the correct handling of the TabHost which is something it seems you have trouble with. :-)

Comment: Oh I'm sorry, I have to mention that this example is done with the compatibility package v4 of Android. You can find it in android-sdk\extras\android\support\v4
But you don't need the stuff for your task.^^